# ImportError: No module named cffi

Tags: python

I encountered this problem when building the runtime environment, most of which can be solved directly with“Apt install pkg”, but CFFI does not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoG1w.png)
Since I am using the Virtualbox virtual machine of ubuntu server, no GUI version, it is not convenient for me to describe the problem in text form, please forgive me, if there is a better way, please feel free to enlighten me.

I have tried several ways to install the CFFI library, but I still notice that it is not available when I build the library
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSbUA.png)